# Excel Operator based on if-formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-statements, operators

I am using Excel 2016. Is it possible to pick the operator based on a condition? If a cell contains the text "absolute" it should do an addition and if the text is "percentage" it should do a multiplication.

I'm trying to shorten my formulas. Right now I am using: `=If(A1="Absolute",C1+B1,C1*B1)`
But what I'd ideally like to have would be something like this: 
`= C1 & If(A1="Absolute",+,*) & B1`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `IF` can only return values, not operators. You could do this with a VBA user-defined function but not sure it'd be worth the effort. You could possibly do it with `AGGREGATE` but I don't think it would shorten the formula.

Comment: The `AGGREGATE` version would be `=AGGREGATE(IF(A1="Absolute",9,6),0,B1:C1)` or something similar.

Comment: Well, the one you are using is actually shorter than what you want (if that's really important to you).  To interpret a string as formula, you can use the `EVALUATE()` function. Assume your desired formula is in D1, create a Named Range with formula `EVALUATE($D$1)`. This serves the task, but I see no value in doing so :)

Comment: Thank you @BigBen! I was actually able to solve this with a user defined function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solved it:

```
Dim FinalPrice As Double

If Add_on = 0 Then
FinalPrice = Price
ElseIf Add_on_Type = "Absolute" Then
FinalRate = Price+ Add_on
ElseIf Add_on_Type = "Percentage" Then
FinalRate = Price* Add_on
Else: MsgBox "Add-on type is neither absolute nor percentage"
End If
CalcAddon = FinalPrice
End Function
```

My function in the cell now looks like this: `=CalcAddon(C1,A1,B1)`